# Why can't I Install 64 bit Ubuntu inside Microsoft Virtual PC?

Tags: installation, 64-bit, virtualbox, intel

I have Intel Core 2 Duo processor which is x86_64, I have installed Microsoft Virtual PC on this Intel laptop, when I tried to install x86_64 Ubuntu(amd64) on my Virtual PC, I get a kernel error message. I really would like to use Ubuntu on this machine.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the error message? Copy it exactly. What version of Windows do you run? 32-bit or 64-bit? How did you do the installation of Ubuntu?

Comment: Why don't you try virtualbox?

Comment: We need the *exact* kernel error. Going about this with the information you have given is similar to trying to read in the dark without knowing where the book is.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr**: Use VirtualBox. Don't use VPC.

Virtual PC 2007 is quite old and no longer under development. It is unlikely that any bugfixes have been put in recently. It also doesn't officially support Linux. Since I don't know the nature of your error or if there is even a fix, I recommend you use [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) as it is still being updated and has great Linux support. Moreover, it is free and open-source, which helps with bugfixes and security. It is very similar:

1. Download and install it
2. Open the program.
3. Click on New at the top.
4. Set the RAM to at least 512MB if possible. 1 or more GB is recommended.
5. Make the disk dynamic and at least 100GB. It uses about 1.8 GB on your host drive once installed and only uses more space on the host as you use space on the guest. Be sure to use the VDI option.
6. Finish up and right click the virtual machine in the menu and click "Settings"
7. Under System->Acceleration, turn on both the VT-x/AMD-V and the nested paging options.
8. Click OK and start the VM.
9. In the first run wizard, point the VM to the ISO file you downloaded for Ubuntu.
10. Boot up and install as usual. You have no risk of damaging your Windows partitions.

[image: Turning on acceleration options]

If you are unable to use AMD-V, or Intel Virtualization technology, turn it on in your BIOS(You probably will have one or the other, not both), and see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118006/amd-v-is-not-enable-in-virtualbox-in-amd-apu/). Note that some BIOSes and processors do not support virtualization.

Comment: Not all Intel Core 2 Duo CPUs support Intel Virtualization so it may not be possible to turn it on. See list in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer, ObsessiveFOSS has it summed up pretty well, but really, unless you're doing Scientific Calculations, managing large MySQL databases, 64bit operating systems are just luxury for the name. 32bit operate just as well, and probably under the Virtual Machine, a little faster. Since this is a 64bit laptop, it's capable of running both 64bit operating systems (x86_64) as well as 32bit operating systems (x86). Again as I quote ObsessiveFOSS, *"Virtual PC 2007 is quite old and no longer under development. It is unlikely that any bugfixes have been put in recently. It also doesn't officially support Linux."* So, I would use 32bit unless you ABSOLUTELY have to use 64, in which I have yet to encounter a situation that forces me into that corner. Virtual Box is a great, free, virtual machine that will run Ubuntu just fine.

Also a tip I would do, is to put the Kernel Error into the question, it might be that the iso was incomplete when downloaded or something along those lines. It would make the question a little bit easier to solve, just as a heads up for future questions!

Comment: That's valid, but 64-bit is useful for more than scientific calculations. It's useful for large MySQL databases, video editing, and in 2003, bragging rights.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS  For the common user, if you're not using it to manage a large MySQL databases, video editing, all in 2003, I think you'll be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't install a 64-bit OS into Virtual PC is, as mentioned, probably because Virtual PC only supports 32-bit operation.

With VirtualBox you can install a 64-bit guest running on a 64-bit host, but only if the CPU supports hardware virtualization, otherwise you must use a 32-bit guest even if the host is running 64-bit.

Not all Intel Core 2 Duo processors support hardware virtualization; specifically it is not supported on the E4000 series (E4300, E4400, E4500 E4600 & E4700), some members of the E7000 series (e.g. E7200, E7300) or the E8190.

You may need to check the actual variant of your CPU if you want to run a 64-bit guest,