# Can't run genymotion, because "AMD-V is disabled"

Tags: 14.10

When I'm going to use genymotion, and open a phone I have chosen, it says "AMD-V is disabled in the BIOS (or by the host OS). (VERR_SVM_DISABLED)". How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AMD-V is not enabled in VirtualBox on AMD APU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118006/amd-v-is-not-enabled-in-virtualbox-on-amd-apu)

Answer (score 0):

It is saying what is the problem. All you have to do is enable AMD-V in the BIOS. It is mostly disabled in BIOS. So, reboot the desktop and enter the bios menu. The traditional way is keep on pressing "Del" key on the keyboard and you'll be seeing the BIOS screen. If it doesn't work, try F12 or F2 etc.

Once you are in the BIOS setup, look for Advanced BIOS settings or something which relates to that phrase. You'll find something related to "Virtualization" there. Just move the arrow keys downwards and enable it. After that press F10 to save and exit setup.