# VirtualboxAMD-V requering even on single core 32bits

Tags: virtualbox

When i launch any virtual machine in Virtualbox get this error:

AMD-V is disabled in the BIOS (or by the host OS) (VERR_SVM_DISABLED).

I am trying to crate a single core virtual pc of 32 bits.

Also when entering to virtualbox there is this warning.

[image]

yet the mentioned option is disabled

My laptop does not come with VT-X/AMD-V option in the bios, regardless of that i have run other single core 32bits virtual stations in the same pc in windows, it gives me the same problem only if use 64 bits.

But now on ubuntu 20.04 get this issue with all machines.

Need to be able to run a virtual machine.

Comment: You can try to use previous VirtualBox versions like 5.1 or 6.0 from https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/ (select deb for focal or previous version here).

Comment: Funny, could not found any installer for focal.

Comment: Turns out Virtualbox 6.1 late uses Virtual Emulation as default, even after using the terminal manager to disable the usage of Virtual Emulation for the current machine, it will keep pooping the same problem and will not run. Had to resign from Virtual Box and try luck with Qemu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AMD-V is not enabled in VirtualBox on AMD APU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118006/amd-v-is-not-enabled-in-virtualbox-on-amd-apu)